# Problema con Datatable y pestañas de Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap, datatables

Tengo una página html que me genera de forma dinámica con FreemarkerTemplate las pestañas y su contenido de la siguiente forma:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12" id="tabsDiv">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="indexTabs">
    <#list plantas as planta>
        <li><a href="#${planta.idPlanta}" data-toggle="tab">${planta.planta}</a></li>
    </#list>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="tabs">
    <br>
    <#list plantas as planta>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="${planta.idPlanta}">
            <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="tabla${planta.idPlanta}">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th align="center">Máquina</th>
                        <th align="center">Estado</th>
                        <th align="center">Piezas Producidas</th>
                        <th align="center">Piezas Retenidas</th>
                        <th align="center">Referencias</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot class="filters">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">Máquina</td>
                        <td align="center">Estado</td>
                        <td align="center">Piezas Producidas</td>
                        <td align="center">Piezas Retenidas</td>
                        <td align="center">Referencias</td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>
                    <#list maquinas as fila>
                        <#if fila.idPlanta == planta.idPlanta>
                            <tr> 
                                <td> ${fila.maquina} </td>
                                <td align="center"> ${fila.estado} </td>
                                <td align="center"> ${fila.totalPiezas} </td>
                                <td align="center"> ${fila.retenidas} </td>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button" onclick="location.href='/listReferencias/${fila.idMaquina}'">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </#if>
                    </#list>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
   </#list>
</div>
```

Luego al final de la página tengo los siguientes scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-select'] = function  ( settings, col )
{
    return this.api().column( col, {order:'index'} ).nodes().map( function ( td, i ) {
        return $('select', td).val();
    } );
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    //Añadimos los filtros al pie de cada columna **//Aquí es donde tengo el problema ya que el id no es #tabla si no #tabla + id_pestaña**
    $('#tabla tfoot td').not(":eq(3),:eq(4),:eq(5)").each( function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="'+title+'" id="'+title+'" />' );
    } );

    //Asignamos carateristicas a la tabla **//Aquí es donde tengo el problema ya que el id no es #tabla si no #tabla + id_pestaña**
    $('#tabla').DataTable({
        "stateSave": true,
        "stateSaveCallback": function (settings, data) {
            // save the filter settings without connecting it to a unique url
            localStorage.setItem("dataTables_filterSettings", JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        "stateLoadCallback": function (settings) {
            // read out the filter settings and apply
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("dataTables_filterSettings"));
        }
    });

    var table = $('#tabla').DataTable(); **//Aquí es donde tengo el problema ya que el id no es #tabla si no #tabla + id_pestaña**
    //Aplicamos los filtros si hemos realizado alguna búsqueda
    table.columns().eq( 0 ).each( function ( colIdx ) {
        if (colIdx == 3 || colIdx == 4 || colIdx == 5) return;
        table.column(colIdx).footer().children[0].value=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("dataTables_filterSettings")).columns[colIdx].search.search;
        $( 'input', table.column( colIdx ).footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            table
                .column( colIdx )
                .search( this.value )
                .draw();
        } );
    } );
} );
```

Los scripts funcionan bien si solo existe una tabla en la página, pero en este caso el id es dinámico y no se como adaptar el script que tengo al id dinámico que tengo para identificar las tablas y poder aplicar el código.

Comment: podria ser tan sencillo como declarar una clase especifica para esas tablas y asi cambiar de $('#tabla') a $('.clase-tablas'), aunque hay otras formas tambien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno la respuesta que me habeis ofrecido es correcta pero la forma de acceder a la tabla no es como comentais ya que la clase se la estabamos asignando a la pestaña.

He conseguido llegar a ellos  con 
`var tabla = $('.claseTab').eq(0).children(0).DataTable();`

Y a partir de aquí ya trabajar con la tabla.

Muchas gracias a los dos.

Comment: si esto responde a tu propia pregunta, la puedes marcar como correcta y así le va a servir a otro usuario que tenga tu mismo problema en el futuro. Saludos y que bueno que lo has resuelto.

Answer (score 2):

Debería ser como menciona @Forcefield de que en vez de utilizar el ID como selector utilices una clase tal como

```
<div class="tab-pane fade miclasecss" id="${planta.idPlanta}">
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="tabla${planta.idPlanta}">                <thead></thead>
...
</table>
```

y en tu script

```
var table = $('.miclasecss').DataTable();
```

Adicionalmente a esto, veo que llamas dos veces al plugin cuando ya lo tienes instanciado en la variable "table" pudiendo volverlo a utilizar directamente desde la variable "table" (solo una opinión)

Comment: No obtengo lo que necesito ya que cuando hace la parte de

Comment: var table = $('.claseTablas').DataTable();
    //Aplicamos los filtros si hemos realizado alguna búsqueda
    table.columns().eq( 0 ).each( function ( colIdx ) {
                 // El each da fallo poerque es null. Es decir no instancia bien la tabla
        } );
    } );